# More elegant syntax for logical operators for equals() method in Java?

Tags: java, syntax, equals

I have some code like so:

```
if (input.equals("north") || input.equals("n")) { direction = Cardinals.NORTH; }
```

Is there any way to use a less verbose syntax for this, along the lines of:

```
if (input.equals("north" || "n") { direction = Cardinals.NORTH; }
```

I know this doesn't work, but I hope there is some equivalent?

Comment: Yup, I've seen this question a couple of times here on SO (so you might want to search around). One way would be to check against an array/list. For your specific case I like the `map`/switch ideas even more though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using the enum directly:

```
public enum Cardinals {
    NORTH("n", "north"),
    SOUTH("s", "south"),
    EAST("e", "east"),
    WEST("w", "west"),
    ERROR("", "");

    private final List<String> matchingStrings;

    Cardinals(String... matchingStringsAr) {
        this.matchingStrings = Arrays.asList(matchingStringsAr);
    }

    public static Cardinals formStr(String str){
        for (Cardinals cardinals : Cardinals.values()){
            if (cardinals.matchingStrings.contains(str)){
                return cardinals;
            }
        }
        return ERROR;
    }

}

// .....

Cardinals direction = Cardinals.formStr("n");
```

Comment: This is a really cool way of doing it. Upvoted for visibility.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Java 7 and assuming `input` to be a String, you can switch on String literals like so

```
switch(input) {
case "n":
case "north":
    direction = Cardinals.NORTH; 
    break;
case "s":
...
}
```

and so on. Very readable!

EDIT: As proposed by @DaoWen in the comments, if you extract this switch into its own method (say `findCardinal(input)`), you can drop the `break;` and just `return` the correct `Cardinal`, which will lead to a nice one-liner where you need the direction like so: `direction = findCardinal(input);`.

Comment: If you can break this part off into its own method, then you can just use `return Cardinals.NORTH` and thus avoid needing the `break` statements.

Comment: I like this option a lot, unfortunately: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted

Comment: @ubanerjea Yes I'm afraid this is only possible starting from Java 7. Is code compatibility for Java 6 or lower mandatory in your project?

Comment: not in this toy project, but in our enterprise java code it's on 1.6 because of compatibility issues with SQL Developer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) -

```
Map<String, Cardinals> cardinals = new HashMap<>();
cardinals.put("north", Cardinals.NORTH);
cardinals.put("n", Cardinals.NORTH);
cardinals.put("s", Cardinals.SOUTH);    // if you also have SOUTH, I mean
```

Store your `Cardinals` here, and then return it like this -

```
direction = cardinals.get(your_string_key);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a list of the options if there are only a few:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

//....

if (Arrays.asList("n", "north").contains(input)) {
    direction = Cardinals.NORTH;
}
```

However, the `Map` idea is probably better if all you're doing based off this is a single assignment. If you'd like to make this even more succinct, you could also lift this into a utility method:

```
public static boolean checkEq(Object needle, Object... haystack) {
    return Arrays.asList(haystack).contains(needle);
}

//....

if (checkEq(input, "n", "north")) {
    direction = Cardinals.NORTH;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] options = { "night","n" };
if (Arrays.asList(options).contains(input))
       { direction = Cardinals.NORTH; }
```